# Batch file to transfer files with certain phrase in name

Tags: file, batch-file

I currently use a batch code which transfers files from one place to another. I wish to elaborate on that code to only transfer files which have a certain phrase in their file name.

I did not write the code, and I do not fully understand it but I know what is does.

```
  REM choose desired drive
    cd \

Z:

REM change to required directory
cd out

REM cpy all files using * to the desired directory
copy *.dat \\server\f\rug_data\received_transfer

REM delete all files in the folder
REM del *.usr
```

All I want to do now is add a bit which says only transfer files with 'D0036' in their name.

I have spent time googling but could not find exactly what I was after.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: so instead of \*.dat, you want \*D0036\* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
copy *.dat \\server\f\rug_data\received_transfer
```

to

```
copy *D0036* \\server\f\rug_data\received_transfer
```

OR, if you mean "All .dat files with D0036 in their name"

```
copy *D0036*.dat \\server\f\rug_data\received_transfer
```

`*` means "match any number of any characters"

Comment: Thank you, second option, also added by Mark below works perfectly. Thank you both. I feel a bit silly as that's pretty simple!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
copy *D0036*.dat \\server\f\rug_data\received_transfer
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. It works great.

Answer (score -1):

This works like a charm!

```
move /-y "C:\(Folder that the contains files)*(Specify a certain character)*" "C:\(Dest Folder)"
```

This will move everything in the folder with the name that you wrote.

Hope it works!

Logan

Comment: Was the minus necessary?

Comment: It's probably because this is a very late answer (the question got an accepted answer over a year ago), doesn't answer the question being asked (it was asking how to give a wildcard to a `copy` command, you gave a `move` command), etc.